# Hide/Show Richtextbox Bottom Border in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, border, richtextbox

i want to hide/show bottom border of richtextbox in WPF.I already use 10,10,10,-10 for hiding bottom border.it works.but my text content are partially shown for using this method and i cant get the proper panning.So how to hide/show bottom border without extent the value in negative.

Regards
Arjun

Answer (score 3):

Set the bottom border thickness to 0.

```
BorderThickness="10,10,10,0"
```